# Webpack 4 HMR not fully working, can't figure out why

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-hmr

I'm trying to set up a frontend build pipeline with Webpack + Typescript, running into an issue with HMR, it's almost there. It seems to be working for `SCSS` and most `Typescript` and `JS` files but for some strange reason, it's choking on the `index.ts` entry file when I made changes to it.

**Git repo:**

```
https://github.com/LifeSource/frontend-build
```

**webpack.common.js**

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const ErrorOverlayPlugin = require('error-overlay-webpack-plugin')
const ExtractCssChunks = require('extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin')

const babelOptions = {
  presets: [['@babel/preset-env'], '@babel/preset-typescript'],
}

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV // used to check the NODE environment mode.

const isDev = env === 'development'

console.log('isDev: ', isDev)

module.exports = {
  entry: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.ts')],
  output: {
    filename: 'app.bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  watch: isDev ? true : false,
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.json'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        use: [{ loader: 'babel-loader', options: babelOptions }],
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'babel-loader', options: babelOptions },
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
              transpileOnly: true,
            },
          },
        ],
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [
          // HMR SCSS was not working properly with ExtractCssChunks plugin, so had to used this setup
          isDev ? 'style-loader' : ExtractCssChunks.loader,
          'css-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          // HMR for SCSS was not working properly with ExtractCssChunks plugin, so had to used this setup
          isDev ? 'style-loader' : ExtractCssChunks.loader,
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          'css-loader',
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 8192, // in bytes
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new ErrorOverlayPlugin(),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new ExtractCssChunks({
      filename: 'app.styles.css',
      chunkFilename: '[id].css',
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.html'),
    }),
  ],
}
```

***webpack.dev.js***

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const common = require('./webpack.common.js')

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    watchContentBase: true,
    compress: true,
    hot: true,
  },
})
```

***index.ts***

```
import App from './App'
import './styles/styles.scss'
import { listProduct } from './product'

listProduct({ name: 'A4 exercise book', cost: 2.5 })
console.log(App)

if (module && module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept()
}
```

*** NPM build scripts ***

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.dev.js",
    "server-build": "browser-sync start --server dist --files \"**/*.*\"",
    "lint": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx .",
    "prettier": "prettier --ignore-path .gitignore --write \"**/*.+(js|jsx|json|ts|tsx)\"",
    "format": "npm run prettier -- --write",
    "check-format": "npm run prettier -- --list-different",
    "check-types": "tsc",
    "test": "jest",
    "validate": "npm-run-all --parallel check-types check-format lint && npm run test",
    "prebuild": "npm run validate",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.prod.js"
  }
```

***How to produce the error:***

1. Clone the repo above and npm install the packages.
2. Do an `npm run start`.
3. Go to the `index.ts` file and remove a closing quote from any of the `import` statement and hit save.
4. Add the closing quote back and hit save again.

**Expected result**
HMR to refresh and fixed the app and load the page.

**Actual result**
It hangs, doesn't rebuild the `index.ts` file changes.

**NOTE:** SCSS files works like a charm, no issues found yet.